# The Maclaurin Series for holomorphic function f

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, residue-calculus

> $\textbf{Exercise} 
> \quad $Let $R>1$ and let $f$ be holomorphic on $\vert z \vert <R$ except at $z=1$, where $f$ has a simple pole. If
>   \begin{align*}
> f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n \quad (\vert z \vert <1)
> \end{align*}
>   is the Maclaurin series for $f$, show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n$ exists.

We knew that $a_n= f^n(0)/n!$. But, I don't know how to use fact $f$ has a simple pole at $z=1$.

Any help is appreciated ... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $(1-z)f(z)$ exends to be holomorphic in $D(0,R).$  This implies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n-a_{n-1})z^n$ has radius of convergence at least $R.$

Comment: Then, $a_n-a_{n-1}= ((1-z)f(z))^n(0)/n!$. How to know $\lim a_n$ ?

Comment: I got $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} (a_n-a_{n-1}) =0 $. I don't know how to get $\lim a_n$...

Comment: Further hint: The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n-a_{n-1})z^n$ converges absolutely for $|z|<R,$ in particular for $z=1.$

Comment: At $z=1$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n-a_{n-1}) = \lim _{N \rightarrow \infty } a_N-a_0 = 0$. This implies $\lim a_n = a_0 =f(0)$. Right?

Comment: Well yes and no. The convergence of the series shows the limit of $a_N$ exists. And your end game was simpler than what I was thinking. I thought we needed absolute convergence, but your idea shows we don't. Good job there. But no, we don't know $\lim a_n = f(0).$ For example, if $f(z) = z/(1-z),$ the limit of the $a_n$'s is $1\ne f(0) = 0.$

Comment: Thank you! I make a mistake  $(1-z) f(z) =0 $ at $z=1$.

Comment: I modify $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n -a_{n-1}) = \lim _{N\rightarrow \infty} (a_N-a_0) = -Res_{z=1} f(z) $.